# Does PayPal Preapproval guarantee that the funds are available?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal Adaptive Payments in the Classic API (Java).

If I get a Preapproval on a transaction, does that in fact guarantee the funds will be available at the later date? Or does it just give me the ability to attempt capture at a later date? i.e. am I in danger of not being able to collect the funds at the later date?

Comment: I'm assuming it's similar to receiving a token to authorize a charge, it does not mean that the funds will go through 100%.

Answer (score 1):

It does NOT guarantee the funds will be available.  It simply provides you with the ability to attempt a transaction on behalf of the 3rd party without further approval, but if their funding source(s) fail then the payment will indeed fail.

Comment: Interesting that I just called them and asked. I was told it does guarantee the funds - but I don't believe them...

Comment: Yeah...whoever told you that is incorrect.  They must have been thinking about Authorizations, but even then it's only guaranteed for a short period of time.